# Nested $.get in .each

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having trouble when trying to implement a delay to a jQuery loop function (.each).
The problem is: I have a list of rows with multiple columns, where the user needs to enter his data.
Now when the user clicks on a button save, all rows needs to be retrieved one by one and their data inserted in a database.

1st get inserts the data and return the last inserted id. Then in the second $.get that last inserted id is used as a history entry.

The code below works as it should, the only problem is the whole procedure is being finished before the nested $.get starts. So all data inserted by the second $.get is the same.

The function getIdNumber removes unwanted characters from the id (ex from row_1 to 1)

```
$('.data_row').each(function(i){
    id = getIdNumber(this.id);

    setTimeout(function() {

    date = $('#dat_'+id).val();
    customer = $('#cus_'+id).val();
    amount_paid = $('#amt_'+id).val();
    remarks = $('#rem_'+id).val();
    account = $('#acc_'+id).val();

       url = "bin/_receipts.php?addreceipts=&date="+date+"&customer="+customer+"&amountpaid="+amount_paid+"&remarks="+remarks+"&paidaccount=" + account;

       $.get(url, function(d){

          url2 = "bin/_ledgerHandler.php?addaudittrail=&user="+escape("<? echo $_SESSION["user_id"]; ?>")+"&trantype="+escape("Receipt - "+d+"")+"&val="+escape(amount_paid)+"&category=receipts";
          $.get(url2, function(){  

          });                    

       });         

    }, 1000*i);

 });
```

Comment: Ajax is asynchronous, don't forget that. If you want to chain them, you'll need to use callbacks.

Comment: You shouldn't send one request per row, that's a lot traffic. Can't you combine them?

Comment: I could but since the list can be expanded by the user to how much rows he wants then it would make it a bit tricky to send all that info in the url at once. I haven't tried it to be honest and thanks

Comment: do NOT use irrelevant tags. Your question is not related to PHP.

Comment: That's because all your variables are **global**. Each iteration will update them with new values. Use `var variableName = ...` to make them **local**! JavaScript 101: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your second $.get, rather than using the values you calculated before the first get, you need to include everything the second $.get needs in the data result of the first get. That way you can guarantee that all the data for the second $.get is relevant to the result of the first.

In other words, don't use the values of amount_paid in you second $.get, instead return any needed values in your data along with the last insert id.

Comment: Tried this suggestion but still the same problem.

Comment: Ok, finally got this to work. I had to remove the delay and it worked normally. Thanks !